# How does TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE behave when exporting data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DATA (
    MY_DATA_ID NUMBER(38,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    THE_DATA VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DATA_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

(Note that `TIMESTAMP` without further qualification defaults to the data type used above.)

What happens if I export this data using Data Pump and then import it into another database that has a different time zone? Will the stored time be adjusted for the new time zone, or will it behave as though the off set was changed without changing the rest of the data?

For example, if

- The original database is US Central time
- A row contains `2017-10-25 12:14:38`
- We import the data into a database using US Eastern time

will the time be adjusted to `2017-10-25 12:14:38 -04:00` (as in replacing the offset without changing the date/time) or `2017-10-25 13:14:38 -04:00` (= `2017-10-25 12:14:38 -05:00`)?

My apologies for not testing this myself. I don't have access to another database with a different time zone, but I wish to know to inform my choice of data type.

Comment: I think I know the answer because `TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` *doesn't store* time zone info, but I'd like confirmation that my understanding is correct.

Comment: You can edit your own question to put in extra information!

Comment: Can't you import the data and then (keeping track of the new records) check. If it's correct by yoiur criteria, happy days. If not, `UPDATE tbl.newtime SET newtime = newtime + 1hr WHERE tbl.just_inserted = TRUE;` - not sure of Oracle syntax, but you get the drift!

Comment: @Vérace Not without creating an entirely new database. The database's time zone is a configuration value global to the entire DB: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions039.htm.

Comment: I've always thought that databases should store **UTC** and **UTC only!** Let the client sort out what it means locally!

Comment: @Vérace Then the client has to know that you stored everything in UTC; this is hidden knowledge. The *ideal* solution is if the time zone is actually *part of* the data (and is returned back to the client with that data automatically), irrespective of what time zone it's stored in.

Comment: It's not hidden if it's fully documented! Inserting data with TZ also requires the knowledge to do that correctly! Swings and roundabouts! I prefer the UTC storage solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67678/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-verace).

Comment: @Vérace, no for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` type the data is stored in `DBTIMEZONE` - which can be freely configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test and exported table MY_DATA as given in your example.

Then I had a look at the dmp-File using a HEX editor. The file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <STRMTABLE_T>
            <VERS_MAJOR>1</VERS_MAJOR>
            <VERS_MINOR>1 </VERS_MINOR>
            <VERS_DPAPI>3</VERS_DPAPI>
            <ENDIANNESS>2</ENDIANNESS>
            <CHARSET>WE8ISO8859P1</CHARSET>
            <NCHARSET>AL16UTF16</NCHARSET>
            <DBTIMEZONE>+01:00</DBTIMEZONE>
            <FDO>0000006001240F050B0C030C0C0504050D0609070805050505050F05050505050A050505050504050607080823472347081123081141B0470083001F07D00300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</FDO>
            <OBJ_NUM>3286546</OBJ_NUM>
            <OWNER_NAME>PMDSYS</OWNER_NAME>
            <NAME>MY_DATA</NAME>
            <PROPERTY>536870912</PROPERTY>
            <COL_LIST>
                <COL_LIST_ITEM>
                    <OBJ_NUM>3286546</OBJ_NUM>
                    <COL_NUM>1</COL_NUM>
                    <INTCOL_NUM>1</INTCOL_NUM>
                    <SEGCOL_NUM>1</SEGCOL_NUM>
                    <COL_SORTKEY>1</COL_SORTKEY>
                    <BASE_INTCOL_NUM>1</BASE_INTCOL_NUM>
                    <BASE_COL_TYPE>0</BASE_COL_TYPE>
                    <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
                    <NAME>MY_DATA_ID</NAME>
                    <TYPE_NUM>2</TYPE_NUM>
                    <LENGTH>22</LENGTH>
                    <PRECISION_NUM>38</PRECISION_NUM>
                    <SCALE>0</SCALE>
                    <NOT_NULL>1</NOT_NULL>
                    <CHARSETID>0</CHARSETID>
                    <CHARSETFORM>0</CHARSETFORM>
                    <CHARLENGTH>0</CHARLENGTH>
                </COL_LIST_ITEM>
                <COL_LIST_ITEM>
                    <OBJ_NUM>3286546</OBJ_NUM>
                    <COL_NUM>2</COL_NUM>
                    <INTCOL_NUM>2</INTCOL_NUM>
                    <SEGCOL_NUM>2</SEGCOL_NUM>
                    <COL_SORTKEY>2</COL_SORTKEY>
                    <BASE_INTCOL_NUM>2</BASE_INTCOL_NUM>
                    <BASE_COL_TYPE>0</BASE_COL_TYPE>
                    <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
                    <NAME>THE_DATA</NAME>
                    <TYPE_NUM>1</TYPE_NUM>
                    <LENGTH>10</LENGTH>
                    <NOT_NULL>1</NOT_NULL>
                    <CHARSETID>31</CHARSETID>
                    <CHARSETFORM>1</CHARSETFORM>
                    <CHARLENGTH>10</CHARLENGTH>
                </COL_LIST_ITEM>
                <COL_LIST_ITEM>
                    <OBJ_NUM>3286546</OBJ_NUM>
                    <COL_NUM>3</COL_NUM>
                    <INTCOL_NUM>3</INTCOL_NUM>
                    <SEGCOL_NUM>3</SEGCOL_NUM>
                    <COL_SORTKEY>3</COL_SORTKEY>
                    <BASE_INTCOL_NUM>3</BASE_INTCOL_NUM>
                    <BASE_COL_TYPE>0</BASE_COL_TYPE>
                    <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
                    <NAME>DATA_TIMESTAMP</NAME>
                    <TYPE_NUM>231</TYPE_NUM>
                    <LENGTH>11</LENGTH>
                    <SCALE>6</SCALE>
                    <NOT_NULL>1</NOT_NULL>
                    <CHARSETID>0</CHARSETID>
                    <CHARSETFORM>0</CHARSETFORM>
                    <CHARLENGTH>0</CHARLENGTH>
                </COL_LIST_ITEM>
            </COL_LIST>
        </STRMTABLE_T>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

As you can see, it contains information `<DBTIMEZONE>+01:00</DBTIMEZONE>`, so we can assume when you import such file into anther database running on different `DBTIMEZONE`  the values will be properly converted.